# Cannot get converse.js to work in embedded mode with local server

Tags: javascript, converse.js

I cannot get converse.js web client to work in embedded mode. It works okay in fullscreen or overlayed mode (just change the `view_mode` attribute).

My code below works perfectly well in fullscreen mode, but renders a blank screen as soon as I set `view_mode` to 'embedded'. The exact error that appears when inspecting the issue is the below error.

> Error: Plugin "converse-muc-views" tried to override ControlBoxView
>   but it's not found. converse.js:33145:17
>
> Error: Plugin "converse-fullscreen" tried to override ControlBoxView
>   but it's not found.

This is on conversejs latest version (4.0.6)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="conversejs/converse.css" />
    <script src="conversejs/converse.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <style>
      .converse-container {
        height: 55vh;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      converse.initialize({
          allow_otr: true,
          auto_list_rooms: false,
          auto_subscribe: false,
          bosh_service_url: 'http://localhost:7070/http-bind',
          debug: true,
          hide_muc_server: false,
          prebind: false,
          show_controlbox_by_default: true,
          xhr_user_search: false,
          view_mode: 'embedded',
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="converse-container">
      <div id="conversejs"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Instead of getting the embedded viewer, I get a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with 4.1.2 and found that using the additional initialize() argument of:

```
blacklisted_plugins: ['converse-muc-views', 'converse-fullscreen'],
```

will avoid the error. `converse-fullscreen` is presumably not needed for embedded, though why `converse-muc-views` has an issue I had assumed was because I had set

```
allow_muc: false
```

as I am only using direct private communication with a single user in my application. You appear to be using muc (Multi User Conversations) so it looks like there is, or was, an issue.